# How to initialize textviews outside the item click listener

Tags: android, json, listview

I just wanna change my textview color based on JSON result, when statusspp is SPP textview color is RED, and when statusspp is SP2D then textview color is Green. 
My Code Below is initialize textview (code) in OnclickListener : 
So, the textview change only if i must to click it, i mean textview immediately change when i execute that code.

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, toiletList,
                    R.layout.list_view,
                    new String[]{TAG_NPWP, TAG_STATUSSPP, TAG_TGLSP2D, TAG_JUMLAH}, new int[]{
                    R.id.name,R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude,R.id.price});

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv=getListView();

            // Memberikan Event Click Listener pada List View
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    TextView name =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    String npwp = name.getText().toString();
                    TextView text =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.latitude);
                    String statusspp = text.getText().toString();
                    if(statusspp.equals("SPP")){
                        text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);}//to change background}
                        else if(statusspp.equals("SP2D")){
                            text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);}//to change background}
                    TextView tgl =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.longitude);
                    String tglsp2d = tgl.getText().toString();
                    TextView jml =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
                    String jumlahtotal = jml.getText().toString();
```

Comment: See here [Custom adapter implementation](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown)

Comment: whatever you have written is correct but write the same thing in a BaseAdapter getView() method.This can ease your work.

Comment: please help, would you give me a sample code, and where i have to place it. Sorry im a newbie

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom `Adapter` for your `ListView` and make the color changes you need there.

I would recommend you to always use custom `Adapters` as they provide full control to the programmer.

PS- By custom adapters I mean, you should create your own `Adapter`.